# foreign key relationships and auto-incrementing in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, import

I have two instances of a database with these two tables:

1. Foo

foo_id <-- primary key

2. Bar

bar_id <-- primary key

foo_id <-- foreign key

---

bar_id and foo_id are automatically incremented, read only primary keys.

What I want to do is this:

- On database instance 1, I drop all the rows in foo and bar
- Import the rows from database 2 to database 1

How can I keep the relationship between tables Foo and Bar in this setup? That is, whatever the primary key in Foo is, the corresponding row in Bar has the right foreign key value to Foo no matter what value foo_id has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can issue the command

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON
```

before inserting values into a table and call

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF
```

afterwards.

According to the documentation for [SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.

and

> If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the current identity value.

To keep the foreign key relationship simply import the main table (Foo) before the details table (Bar).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to truncate tables foo and bar on db1 so the identity seed is reset

You will need to "set identity insert on" on foo and bar on db1

Load tables foo and bar on db1 from tables foo and bar on db2.

Turn identity insert off

[IDENTITY INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

You may need to reseed the next identity value in foo and bar since you loaded rows from db2

[DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)